# Migration of website VS2010 to VS2015 throwing error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, migration

Recently, I have moved/opened my VS2010 website(.net framework 3.5) to VS2015 website(.net framework 3.5).

When I run the website with default page, I'm getting error as:

> "Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found."

But then again open the same project with VS2010 and run, it is opening the page without error.

As a next step, I try upgrading VS2015 website project framework 3.5 to 4.5.2 with some web.config changes. but the still issue remain same.

Help me on the above issue to run website on VS2015.

Comment: What resource cannot be found?

Comment: Im running with default.aspx page. so error is "Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found." and bottom. Requested URL: /default.aspx